# Mapbox Geocoding API - 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' error

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, mapbox

I'm trying to call Geocoding API but I'm not having any luck. I keep receiving the following error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.mapbox.com/gecoding/v5/mapbox.places/fort%20coll…7nugng&autocomplete=true&bbox=-105.214,40.451,-104.85,40.841. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

When I add the header it says it can't run the script. Not sure what else to do. My link is formated properly because it works in mapbox [search-Playground](https://www.mapbox.com/search-playground/)

```
var searchId = document.getElementById('mySearch');
searchId.addEventListener('keyup', function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log(searchId.value)
        var urlBase = 'https://api.mapbox.com/gecoding/v5/mapbox.places/';
        var location = searchId.value;
        var bbox = [-105.214, 40.451, -104.850, 40.841]

        var query = urlBase + location + '.json?access_token=' + mapboxgl.accessToken + '&autocomplete=true&bbox=' + bbox;
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: query,
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data)
            }
          })
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell us what it says exactly? Try to add an error callback and log that

Comment: sorry, not sure how to do that. Is there a way I can look in the web console? I should also note this ajax method works with their Isochrone API